# Searching custom metadata fields in Adobe Bridge by default

Tags: adobe-bridge

I have a bunch of metadata embedded into my images in a custom xmp namespace that I've defined. Unfortunately, Bridge does not search the metadata by default when I perform a search. Instead, I have to open up the find window and explicitly tell it to include all metadata fields in its search in order for it to work the way I want it to.

Is there a way to make this the default behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Bridge Quicksearch looks only at keywords and file/folder names. Only the Find dialog searches metadata, but the option is sticky. If you perform a search using metadata, Find will remember your choice after you quit Bridge.

Comment: I've figured that much out. I was hoping there was a way to alter the behavior of the Quicksearch so that it searches metadata as well so that people at my company don't have to open Find every time they want to do a search.

Comment: You could build a custom search script tied to the Quicksearch event, probably, but there's no option to set special parameters for Quicksearch otherwise. (But... really? One keystroke is too many?)